# How to convert firebase timestamp to user date format using Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got example from Stack Overflow but result is wrong, when I added to my project solution from Stack Overflow 
code 

`Seen {{adr.a_t * 1000 | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</p><Br>result <br>Seen 12-14-50689`

I tried [this](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) website but result is wrong
my `timestamp ="1537453221451"` and the website given wrong result

> 1537453221451
>  Is equivalent to:
>  12/14/50689 @ 11:17am
>   (UTC)
>  50689-12-14T11:17:31+00:00 in ISO 8601
>  Sat, 14 Dec 50689
>   11:17:31 +0000 in RFC 822, 1036, 1123, 2822
>  Saturday, 14-Dec-89
>   11:17:31 UTC in RFC 2822
>  50689-12-14T11:17:31+00:00 in RFC
>   3339

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use method .toDate() to convert firestore timestamps into js dates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate)